# How to print the line numbers with corresponding line that matches a pattern using shell command?

Tags: shell, shell-script, text-processing, awk

File,

```
.false alarm is bla no. 11
.no alarm generated is bla
.application will be killed is bla wall command
.doc file is document file with .doc extension
.no authority for this selection bla
```

Now what I want in my output file to print the lines which contains only the word `bla` (Or it may be number also)

Output will be like this,

```
1 .false alarm is bla no. 11
2 .no alarm generated is bla
3 .application will be killed is bla wall command
5 .no authority for this selection bla
```

Comment: awk 'i++ {if($1~/RRBS/) print i}' ../../bak/bak.db

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Many tools can be handy:

- `-n` of `grep` is exactly what you are looking for.

  ```
  grep -n 'bla' file
  ```
- alternatively `awk`:

  ```
  awk '/bla/{print NR":"$0}' file
  ```
- alternatively `perl`:

  ```
  perl -ne 'print $.,":",$_ if /bla/' file
  ```
- alternatively `sed`:

  ```
  sed '/bla/!d;=' file |sed 'N;s/\n/:/'
  ```

Comment: :-) yes... got the desired output. @jimmij

Comment: sed can also be `sed -n '/bla/!d;=;p' file`