# Sed to print out the line number

Tags: sed, grep

Here is my sample file

```
user@linux:~$ cat file.txt 
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
user@linux:~$
```

I can print line 2-4 with `grep -A2 'e 2' file.txt`

```
user@linux:~$ grep -A2 'e 2' file.txt 
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
user@linux:~$
```

I can also print out the line number as well with `grep -n`

```
user@linux:~$ grep -nA2 'e 2' file.txt 
2:Line 2
3-Line 3
4-Line 4
user@linux:~$
```

Also, the same thing can be accomplished with `sed -n 2,4p file.txt`

```
user@linux:~$ sed -n 2,4p file.txt 
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
user@linux:~$
```

But I'm not sure how to print out the line number with `sed`

Would it be possible to print out the line number with `sed`?

Comment: Why `sed` and not `awk 'NR==2,NR==4{print NR" "$0}' file.txt`.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know it can be accomplished with `awk`. I've just reading about `sed` and wondering if it can do the same thing.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**AWK:**

```
awk 'NR==2,NR==4{print NR" "$0}' file.txt
```

Double **sed:**

```
sed '2,4!d;=' file.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
```

[glen jackmann](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman)'s **sed** and **paste:**

```
sed '2,4!d;=' file.txt | paste -d: - -
```

[bart](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/152035/bart)'s **Perl** version:

```
perl -ne 'print "$. $_" if 2..4' file.txt
```

**cat** and **sed:**

```
cat -n file.txt | sed -n '2,4p'
```

---

Also see this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225446/265461) to a similar question.

A bit of **explanation:**

- `sed -n '2,4p'` and `sed '2,4!d'` do the same thing: the first only prints lines between the second and the fourth (inclusive), the latter "deletes" every line except those.
- `sed =` prints the line number *followed by a newline*. See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-_003d-_0028print-line-number_0029-command).
- `cat -n` in the last example can be replaced by `nl` or `grep -n ''`.

Comment: also sed+paste is very readable: `sed '2,4!d;=' file | paste -d: - -`

Comment: With Perl  you don't have to explicitly compare to `$.`, just the line number literal is enough: `perl -ne 'print "$.  $_" if 2 .. 4' file.txt`  or `perl -ne '2 .. 4 and print "$.  $_"' file.txt`

Answer (score 3):

I have done by below mentioned 2 methods

Method1

```
awk '/2/{x=NR+2}(NR<=x){print NR"-"$0 }' filename
```

command

```
2-Line 2
3-Line 3
4-Line 4
```

Method2

```
sed -n '{;=;p}' filename| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"| sed -n '/2/,+2p'
```

output

```
2 Line 2
3 Line 3
4 Line 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this exactly the sort of thing `nl` is for?

**[`nl` - line numbering filter](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nl.html)**

Then you can use any method you wish to select lines.

(EDIT)

Per [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nl.html), `nl` *does* number empty lines:

```
$ nl -b a example
     1  line1
     2  
     3  line3
     4  
     5  line5
     6
```

```
$ nl -b a < example | sed -n '2,4p'
     2  
     3  line3
     4
```

You can reverse the pipe if you only want to count the output instead.

Comment: Since `nl` does not number blank lines, you should probably show a full example of how you would envisage using the utility to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: I do not know why you say `nl` does not number blank lines, but I have added an example anyway.

Comment: Yes, using `-b a` with `nl` numbers all lines, but you never said anything about using that particular combination of arguments in your initial answer, hence my first comment.   ... now the only issue is lines that are `\:`, `\:\:` and `\:\:\:`.  These are special instructions to `nl` to treat the following lines as header, body or footer lines.